# Class with ternery expression with no true statement?

Tags: javascript

```
class EditorState{
static createWithText(
    text: string,
    decorator?: ?DraftDecoratorType,
  ): EditorState {
    return EditorState.createWithContent(
      ContentState.createFromText(text),
      decorator,
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone explain what this code does?

especially `decorator?: ?DraftDecoratorType,` isn't it ternery operator like if-statement?

Comment: That looks like TypeScript, that has some additional syntax...

Comment: This is typescript, `decorator?` means `decorator` is an optional argument

Comment: This is not typescript, but flowtype `decorator?` is optional parameter, `?DraftDecoratorType` is maybe type. Better start from the docs https://flow.org/en/docs/types/

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [TypeScript function definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) which includes additional typing information.

It's not a ternary, here `decorator?:` means that `decorator` is an optional argument.

Comment: This is not typescript, but flowtype

Comment: @AlekseyL. Worth adding as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not ternary expression, but [flowtype](/questions/tagged/flowtype) [annotations](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/).

`decorator?` is [optional parameter](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-optional-parameters)

> Optional parameters will accept missing, `undefined`, or matching types. But they will not accept `null`

`?DraftDecoratorType` is [maybe type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/)

> Maybe types accept the provided type as well as `null` or `undefined`